# Can't convert Expression<Int> to Expression<AnyObject>

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

I am using [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) library.

I have several `Expression`s,

```
let idColumn = Expression<Int>("id")
let nameColumn = Expression<String>("name")
```

I would like to have a dictionary host them, So, I did:

```
let columns: [String: Expression<AnyObject>] = [
   "id": idColumn,
   "name": nameColumn
]
```

But I get compiler error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Expression<Int>' to expected dictionary value type 'Expression<AnyObject>'
```

Why is this error? Why `Int` type can’t be `AnyObject`?

I also tried Any instead of `AnyObject`:

```
let columns: [String: Expression<Any>] = [
       "id" : idColumn,
       "name": nameColumn
    ]
```

Similar error shows:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Expression<Int>' to expected dictionary value type 'Expression<Any>'
```

I don't understand this... Could someone please explain to me?

Comment: `Expression<Int>` and `Expression<Any>` are different types and casting doesn't work on restricted generic types. Why don't you declare both `idColumn` and `nameColumn` as `Expression<Any>`?

Comment: I have no experience with SQLite.swift (or SQLite), but this looks like what their [`cast(_:)`](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Sources/SQLite/Typed/Expression.swift#L141) function is for. Generics [are invariant in the general case though](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41976844/2976878).

Comment: Because generics in general are not covariant on their parameterized type. Inheritance / polymorphism does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

Your expectations are wrong; what you expect is not how the Swift language works. I'll just repeat the example I give in my book:

> A generic type specialized to a subtype is not polymorphic with respect to the same generic type specialized to a supertype. For example, suppose we have a simple generic struct along with a class and its subclass:

```
struct Wrapper<T> {
}
class Cat {
}
class CalicoCat : Cat {
}
```

> Then you can’t assign a Wrapper specialized to CalicoCat where a Wrapper specialized to Cat is expected:

```
let w : Wrapper<Cat> = Wrapper<CalicoCat>() // compile error
```

Technically, we say that generics are not covariant on their parameterized type. There are exceptions to that rule — Optional is the obvious one — but they have to be baked into the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

Naked `Int` and `String` types can be converted to `AnyObject`. But this does not apply when they are wrapped in a generic type: `Expression<Int>` can not be converted to `Expression<AnyObject>`. That's how Swift works today (Swift 4):

```
// OK
let i: Int = 1
let i2 = i as AnyObject

// Error: cannot convert value of type 'S<Int>' to type 'S<AnyObject>' in coercion
struct S<T> { }
let s = S<Int>()
let s2 = s as S<AnyObject>
```

Besides, even if it would, the expressions you would extract from the dictionary would have lost their column type: you could not use them directly in SQLite.swift, as exemplified by your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308938/how-to-use-filter-to-update-row-in-sqlite-swift-library).